# Java Clock Advancing Time

Tags: java, time, clock

Struggling with some java homework, why isn't this working? Advance brings in minutes. If its over 59 minutes then it adds to my hourly counter. Then I check to see if hours count over 12 to change the AM/PM status. This needs to repeatedly bring in numbers and continually add. I left out the other code as this is the part I'm supposed to be able to do.

```
public void advance(int advance) {
   int whichAmPm = 0;
   minute += advance;
   if (minute > 59) {
       hour++;
       minute = (minute - 60);
   }
   if (hour > 12) {
       hour = (hour - 12);
       whichAmPm++;
   }
   if (whichAmPm % 2 == 0) {
        amPm = amPm;
    } else if (whichAmPm % 2 !=0) {
        if (amPm == "AM") {
            amPm = amPm.replaceAll("A", "P");
         } else {
            amPm = amPm.replaceAll("P", "A");
     }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Should the line `amPm = amPm;` do something else?  Right now it essentially does nothing.

Comment: Strings should be compared through `equals`, not `==`: `if (amPm == "AM") {`

Comment: @MikeNakis Someone else was able to help me, so maybe you should get off your high horse.

Comment: Pauline, if you take a look at the time that my comment was posted, you will notice that I was perfectly well aware that you have received your answers.  Nonetheless I do believe that people who answer incomplete or badly formulated questions on stackoverflow should be penalized.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9nXfffeAIU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop (instead of using `if` statements). You can use `-=` (like `x -= y`) instead of `x = x - y`. And you compare `Object` types (like `String`) with `.equals`, `==` tests reference equality. Finally, you might use a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). I think you wanted something like,

```
public void advance(int advance) {
    int whichAmPm = 0;
    minute += advance;
    while (minute > 59) {
        hour++;
        minute -= 60;
        if (hour > 12) { // <-- this is safe because the above increments hour once
            hour -= 12;
            whichAmPm++;
        }
    }
    if (whichAmPm % 2 != 0) {
        amPm = amPm.equals("AM") ? "PM" : "AM";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're definitely getting me on track. However, don't I want the if statement for the AM/PM inside the while loop?

Comment: @PaulineGonzalez No need. You have a seperate counter for that field. This algorithm could be simplified, in fact it's already built into Java. Take a look at [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html), and the classes in [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In this case, you do not need to loop over the hours since they can only advance by 1.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I do not see how that is relevant. While you loop over the minutes your hours are always incremented by just 1 inside the minute loop. Unlike minutes, hour can never "jump", e.g., from 7 to 48, which then would require looping.

Comment: @nautical Sorry, I was looking at the wrong loop. Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use some modular mathematics (but one can't discount the simplicity of a loop either)

```
int hour = 8;
int min  = 30;

int advance = 125;

min += advance % 60;
hour += advance / 60;
```

I'd also consider simplifying your am/pm decisions from...

```
if (hour > 12) {
    hour = (hour - 12);
    whichAmPm++;
}
if (whichAmPm % 2 == 0) {
    amPm = amPm;
} else if (whichAmPm % 2 != 0) {
    if (amPm == "AM") {
        amPm = amPm.replaceAll("A", "P");
    } else {
        amPm = amPm.replaceAll("P", "A");
    }
}
```

to something more like...

```
if (hour > 12) {
    hour = (hour - 12);
    amPm = "PM";
} else {
    ampPM = "AM";
}
```

But that's just me

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your method is that it won't work when you add 120 minutes. This is a simple way to achieve what you want with no if statements.

```
public static final int AM = 0, PM = 1;
int hour = 0, minute = 0;
int am_pm = AM;

public void advance(int advance) {
    minute += advance;
    hour += minute / 60;
    minute %= 60;
    am_pm ^= (hour / 12 % 2);
    hour %= 12;
}
```